# UI5 Routed View with binded element as expected, but can't find path correctly

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to get a routed view to show an element from the previous screen, using the following data: 
A JSON model loaded to a model `locationListModel`

```
{
    value: [
        {
            id: 251,
            locationName: "SAP",
            holidayList: [ ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I assume that we can access the `locationName` of this first location using the following path: `{locationListModel>/value/0/locationName}`

So, when routing to another view we could access it like that, or by an Element Binding Context in the view by doing the following:

```
...
    onInit: function() {
        this.getRouter().getRoute("location").attachMatched(this._onObjectMatched, this);
    },
    _onObjectMatched: function(oEvent) {
        this.getView().bindElement({
            path:"/value/" + oEvent.getParameter("arguments").locationId,
            model:"locationListModel"});

    },
...
```

Which shows in the current view: 
[image: current view description]

However, when trying to access it in the view by using `{locationName}`

```
<Page showNavButton="true" navButtonPress="onNavBack">
    <ObjectHeader title="{locationName}"/> //doesn't show
    <ObjectHeader title="{locationListModel>/value/0/locationName}"/> //shows
</Page>
```

We get nothing on the upper header.

This was done referencing the [Navigation and Routing](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/1b6dcd39a6a74f528b27ddb22f15af0d) walkthrough. 
I am fairly new to UI5, and I can't seem to find this info anywhere. I appreciate any help. 
Thank you.

Comment: What do you get in this.getView().getModel("locationListModel")

Comment: Hi Nandan! I get this https://i.imgur.com/QCC1exs.jpg has no oData, it seems.

Comment: I didn't show the binding part: here it is https://i.imgur.com/j8xzsA2.jpg

Comment: Can you also add your router details from the Manifest

Comment: Sure, router class "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router" and "viewType": "XML", routes and targets as follows: https://i.imgur.com/b8zr8Ko.jpg

Comment: All these looks alright. One last thing would be where you call the router. Can you share the part where you call router.navTo()..

Comment: I see, I am getting the data via ajax calls to a restful back end, but I don't think this should be a problem right? The routing navto is currently like this: https://i.imgur.com/5IFIcCJ.jpg, I am using indexof to get the index of which item is pressed on the table. And it returns 0 in this case.

Comment: Yes, loading data from ajax is not an issue. However, In that case, shouldn't you pass the keys or URL of the object you want to bind to the next view instead of the index? Any specific reason behind using the index?

Comment: I passed the id (251) before but couldn't get the binding because {locationListModel>/value/251/locationName} wouldn't work. This "id" field isn't marked as a primary key too, maybe that is relavant, and I am not sure how to do that. So I am using indexof to get the index under that value[{}] of the JSON Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it by putting `{locationListModel>locationName}` in the XML view as

```
<Page showNavButton="true" navButtonPress="onNavBack">
    <ObjectHeader title="{locationListModel>locationName}"/>
</Page>
```

And made improvements in routing thanks to @Nandan Chaturvedi.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, this issue is raised as you might be referring to the example code in the exercise([Navigation and Routing](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/2366345a94f64ec1a80f9d9ce50a59ef) you mentioned above.
[image]

Where this example works fine for passing a URL path in case of oData, it will not work if you are using a JSON example as you have. 
This tries to send the parameter invoicePath to the router as "Invoices/0" which is wrong and you will get the error as below:
[image]

This occurs because the path does not expect a "/" in between. There is a similar thread for this issue: [Routing with parameters does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41930757/routing-with-parameters-does-not-work)

You can fix this issue with passing only the index in the router like

```js
onPress: function(oEvent) {
  var oItem = oEvent.getSource();
  var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
  oRouter.navTo("detail", {

    //invoicePath should be the index. 
    invoicePath: oItem.getBindingContext("invoice").getPath().substr(10)

  });
}
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Hi Nandan! I am passing the locationId as `locationId: oItem.getBindingContext("locationListModel").getPath().substr(7)` now, route is `http://localhost:8000/webapp/test/testStandalone.html#/locationlist/0`. So it is better to read now. I was able to fix it by using `{locationListModel>locationName}` in the XML View. Thanks for your help! I appreciate it!